# Check origin in Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I'm building an app with Rails 5 API. Currently, anyone sending request to my rails server can receive response.

I want to process only those  requests whose origin is mydomain.com

How can I do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross site scripting attacks and same origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012435/cross-site-scripting-attacks-and-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll want to implement CORS on your API.

Simply add `rack-cors` gem.

And add:

```
 #config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do 
    allow do 
          origins 'mydomain.com' resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options] 
     end 
 end
```

Please read carefully its [documentation](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/README.md)

You'll find very useful information there.

Comment: I enabled the rack-cors gem & ran bundle. Put the config code in application.rb But still I'm able to send request from anywhere.

Comment: Are you specifying the allowed origin? Did you stopped and restarted the server so changes are loaded?

Comment: Yeah, specified mydomain.com as origin & restarted the server too.

Comment: Well it's working in Chrome but Safari somehow bypasses it. Can I have a stricter implementation?

Comment: You could specify a header that must bs included in the request to be accepted. However I don't understand why would it work only on chrome.

Comment: Tried again. It isn't about Safari or Chrome, it's about current origin. When I run a local HTML file, it can simply bypass it.

Comment: Check common gotchas in documentation :)